# WPF, reference to object used in XAML

Tags: wpf, events, xaml

I am new to WPF, please do not blame me ;) 
I have the following part in XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" IsEnabled="{Binding PropertiesEnabled}" Margin="0"
            BorderThickness="0" DragDrop1:DropTargetBehavior.IsDropTarget="true"
            MinHeight="300" DragDrop1:DropTargetBehavior.DropType="{x:Type UIP:DataItemViewModel}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding dataItemCollection}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
            AllowDrop="True" KeyDown="listView_KeyDown" MouseUp="listView_MouseUp"
            UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            MaxWidth="Infinity" MaxHeight="1000" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

In the code behind for the view class, I am able to access listView and most of its properties and attributes like IsEnabled, Margin, ItemsSource etc. However, when it comes to DragDrop1, it is not listed.

The reason why I need to get reference to DragDrop1, which is of type DropTargetBehavior, because some events should be fired programmatically.

What could be the cause of missing DragDrop1? How to I get reference to it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is an `AttachedProperty`, so it doesn't actually exist as part of the `ListView` object. You need to use the `AttachedProperty` class name to access the value, and pass it the `ListView` as a parameter to get or set the value.

You can get it using `DragDrop1.DropTargetBehavior.GetIsDropTarget(listView)` or set it using `DragDrop1.DropTargetBehavior.SetIsDropTarget(listView, yourValue)`